# Promise pending even with async/await method

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

I have a service class with a method fetching data from an api:

```
class TenderTableService{
    fetchOngoingTenders =  async ()   =>  {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/tender/');
        let tenderList: Array<Tender> = (JSON).parse(await response.json());
        return tenderList;
    };
}

export default TenderTableService;
```

This class method is used from another file like this:

```
    const tenderTableService : TenderTableService = new TenderTableService();
    const tenderList= tenderTableService.fetchOngoingTenders();
    console.log(tenderList); // -> Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

I can't figure out how to prevent the variable form returning a pending state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `tenderTableService.fetchOngoingTenders();` returns a promise, since it is actually an async function. If you want access to tenderList, you can do it by chaining `.then()` to it, i.e.:

```
const tenderTableService : TenderTableService = new TenderTableService();
tenderTableService.fetchOngoingTenders().then((tenderList) => {
    // Do something with tenderList here
});
```

...that means all the logic that deals with the value of `tenderList` will need to be wrapped in the `.then()` callback. If the code you have above is also wrapped in a function, then you can convert it to an async function and use await:

```
async function yourFunction() {
    const tenderTableService : TenderTableService = new TenderTableService();
    const tenderList = await tenderTableService.fetchOngoingTenders();

    // Do something with tenderList here
}
```